# Jenkins - identify if build is tagged

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, devops

I have a Jenkins job that is hooked to bitbucket and starts with every commit. I want to make another job that listens to the same URL as the first job, but gets triggered only if the build is tagged.

The end flow should be :
If build is tagged -> start 1st job.
If build is not tagged -> start 2nd job.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you can use jenkins [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/)

Have a nice day